I need a good Hash function for folding 64bits into 32bits. I need to map 64bit variables into a 32bit representation
I am using a murmurhash implementation to fold 64bit (uint64_t) values into 32 bits (uint32_t).   To my surprise, I discovered that there were some collisions on 64bit values that only differ by a couple of bits.  While extensive collisions are certain to appear in my application as I pack about 2^30 uint64 integers into uint32, I did not expect collision between bitwise very similar 64bit values.
So looking for a function with a "better" separation of bitwise similar values.  Collisions are not problematic (not a security application), but I need good separation between similar inputs.
I am not even sure if what I found is unusual and perhaps the murmur-hash is fine, just that packing of so many values into so few buckets inevitably leads to this even with a good hash function.

There is no way to "map 64-bit variables into a 32-bit representation" while avoiding collisions with good confidence for more than a few thousands 64-bit inputs, unless something is known about the distribution of the 64-bit inputs. The probability of 32-bit hash collision for $n$ random distinct inputs is about $1-(1-2^{-32})^{n(n-1)/2}$ and that's already >5% for 21000 inputs. I suggest you investigate if your hashes collide more often than expected. That can easily done by counting how many times each 32-bit value (or a subset of that) is reached for your $2^{30}$ 64-bit inputs.

"So looking for a function with a "better" separation of bitwise similar values." - have you considered a CRC?  As long as all the bit differences are confined to an area 32 bits in length (for a CRC with a 32 bit output), the outputs will always be distinct.

"I did not expect collision between bitwise very similar 64bit values" most hash functions randomize the output. In that scenario each input is as likely to collide as the next. CRC's as poncho indicated are constructed differently. Of course "similar" is badly defined. A CRC could still create a collision e.g. if all the bits of the input are flipped.
